# How to decode ink smart contract call and event data?

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, smart-contract, events

I want to decode the contract call data and event data saved in a block. How can I do that?

[image][image]

Answer (score 8):

Having this data in *hex format*, you can decode it using [cargo-contract](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract) command line utility simply like this (*run from the contract src folder*):

```
cargo contract decode -d <data_hex_string> -t message
```

You can decode event and constructor data in the same way by running it with `-t event` and `-t constructor` accordingly.

Comment: Also, note that `cargo contract decode` cannot know which event to decode as the 'data' does not contain the event id. See https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8316/how-to-identify-received-contract-event.

Answer (score 5):

Typically all data is [SCALE encoded](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-scale-codec) for Substrate. You need to decode and parse the result into something human readable, like is done on the [contracts-ui](https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/) from the [contracts-ui github](https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui) and documented in the [polkadot-js contracts docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.read#reading-contract-values)