# How to identify received contract event?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, events

My contract emits several `[ink(event)]` events. My application subscribes to the events and receives [`Contracts_ContractEmitted`](https://github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/blob/015965cf2e670ceb9b87ae40a8ddfe7ee8114a8f/types/events.go#L2961) data (from centrifuge go-substrate-rpc-client). How may I understand which of my events caused this?

From my experiments, I see that `event.Topic[0]` somehow identifies the event - the same event has the same values, different have differents. If so, how is it encoded?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/587/how-to-decode-ink-smart-contract-call-and-event-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What helped me to get a glimpse of this is to [`cargo expand`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) a simple lib.rs file.

I added two `events` to the flipper contract:

```
    #[ink(event)]
    pub struct Created {
        value: bool,
    }

    #[ink(event)]
    pub struct Flipped {
        #[ink(topic)]
        value: bool,
    }
```

I executed `cargo expand --lib > expanded_lib.rs` and somewhere you can find the code where the `topics` are pushed (`push_topic`) to the `TopicsBuilderBackend`.

```
    const _: () = {
        impl ::ink::env::Topics for Created {
           type RemainingTopics = [::ink::env::topics::state::HasRemainingTopics; 1usize];
            fn topics<E, B>(
                &self,
                builder: ::ink::env::topics::TopicsBuilder<
                    ::ink::env::topics::state::Uninit,
                    E,
                    B,
                >,
            ) -> <B as ::ink::env::topics::TopicsBuilderBackend<E>>::Output
            where
                E: ::ink::env::Environment,
                B: ::ink::env::topics::TopicsBuilderBackend<E>,
            {
                builder
                    .build::<Self>()
                    .push_topic::<
                        ::ink::env::topics::PrefixedValue<[u8; 13usize]>,
                    >(
                        &::ink::env::topics::PrefixedValue {
                            value: b"Test::Created",
                            prefix: b"",
                        },
                    )
                    .finish()
            }
        }
    };
    const _: () = {
        impl ::ink::env::Topics for Flipped {
            type RemainingTopics = [::ink::env::topics::state::HasRemainingTopics; 2usize];
            fn topics<E, B>(
                &self,
                builder: ::ink::env::topics::TopicsBuilder<
                    ::ink::env::topics::state::Uninit,
                    E,
                    B,
                >,
            ) -> <B as ::ink::env::topics::TopicsBuilderBackend<E>>::Output
            where
                E: ::ink::env::Environment,
                B: ::ink::env::topics::TopicsBuilderBackend<E>,
            {
                builder
                    .build::<Self>()
                    .push_topic::<
                        ::ink::env::topics::PrefixedValue<[u8; 13usize]>,
                    >(
                        &::ink::env::topics::PrefixedValue {
                            value: b"Test::Flipped",
                            prefix: b"",
                        },
                    )
                    .push_topic::<
                        ::ink::env::topics::PrefixedValue<bool>,
                    >(
                        &::ink::env::topics::PrefixedValue {
                            value: &self.value,
                            prefix: b"Test::Flipped::value",
                        },
                    )
                    .finish()
            }
        }
    };
```

The first topic is the [`PrefixedValue`](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/c1f14bcc1011a36ed72e6726dafb1efbde5bae4d/crates/env/src/topics.rs#L208-L223) of the event itself:

> PrefixedValue { value: b"Test::Created", prefix: b"" }

The second topic is the actual `#[ink(topic)]` in the struct:

> PrefixedValue { value: &self.value, prefix: b"Test::Flipped::value" }

When we add the [`anonymous` attribute](https://use.ink/macros-attributes/anonymous) we get something like:

```
    const _: () = {
        impl ::ink::env::Topics for Created {
            type RemainingTopics = ::ink::env::topics::state::NoRemainingTopics;
            fn topics<E, B>(
                &self,
                builder: ::ink::env::topics::TopicsBuilder<
                    ::ink::env::topics::state::Uninit,
                    E,
                    B,
                >,
            ) -> <B as ::ink::env::topics::TopicsBuilderBackend<E>>::Output
            where
                E: ::ink::env::Environment,
                B: ::ink::env::topics::TopicsBuilderBackend<E>,
            {
                builder.build::<Self>().finish()
            }
        }
    };
```

Where you can see that no topics are pushed to `TopicsBuilderBackend`.

Additional info: [erc20 tests for emitted events](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/9e6c800b498c0da74e9a29fe5470696b63fee49f/erc20/lib.rs#L228-L275).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Genial! This helped a lot. Looking at `encoded_into_hash` source, I found that for event names shorter than 32 chars, their event ids are those names themselves, no hashing :) So "Test::Created" is simply `0x00546573743a3a43726561746564000000000000000000000000000000000000`.